# (mt) gridserver apc resets on request

Tags: php, debian

I've installed apc on mediatemple's gridserver (which runs fastcgi) but it resets on every request (uptime via apc.php shows as 0 and start time shows current server time). I've seen a few related problems on here and elsewhere but none have a real solution.

Has anyone got this working before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering: No, it doesn't work